# Ext.Msg is undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

i am using ExtJs 4 and using this code

Here is the js part

```
Ext.onReady(function () {


//button with handler
Ext.create("Ext.Button",{
text : "Hello World",
handler : function(){
Ext.Msg.alert("Hello World Error");
},
renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});

//panel without data
Ext.create("Ext.Panel",{
title : "Hello World Panel",
items : [
Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text",{
fieldLabel : "Name"
}),
Ext.create("Ext.Button",{
text : "Click"
})
],
renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});

//popup with data
Ext.create("Ext.Panel",{
title : "Hello World Panel",
items : [
Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text",{
fieldLabel : "Name",
id:"nametext"
}),
Ext.create("Ext.Button",{
text : "Click",
handler : function(){
Ext.Msg.alert(Ext.getCmp("nametext").getValue());
}
})
],
renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

});

Here is the Html part

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-debug.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Error : Ext.Msg is not defined , However i am able to see the UI, but none of the handler works.

Please help

Comment: That looks like it should work. Did ext-debug.js load correctly in your browser?

Comment: yeah it loaded correctly.

Comment: Although if i remove this ext-debug.js and add ext-all.js. it works , but dont know the reason why it behave like this.

Comment: You mean if you remove them includes you still see the ext components and the alerts work? If so, you must have other includes in your html?

Comment: yeah 

i remove 

<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-debug.js"></script>

and add

<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>

and now it works

Comment: Hmm ok, you must have the library being included in other references

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to understand when to use `ext-all.js`, `ext-debug.js` and `ext-all-debug.js`

- `ext-debug.js` includes only a small part of the framework. It is intended for use in MVC style, and will load all classes that are declared in any class in a [`requires: []` statement](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires).
- The production version of this is compiles `app.js` file  (compiled with `Sencha Command`)
- `ext-all-debug.js` includes the whole framework for a development in a legacy (non-MVC) style.
- `ext-all.js` includes the whole framework in a legacy (non-MVC) style for the production site (in a minified version).

You should not use `ext-all.js`in your case, but `ext-all-debug.js`.

Also look into [the MVC system](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture) to write better maintainable code.